# Pointer event listener, shape gestures - How? [Graphic Example Included]

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, gesture

**Setup**

I want to create a webpage where, when the user's cursor is in a certain region of the screen, and he "draws" an imaginary circle in that region, javascript detects that gesture and carries out a function. For a square, a different function would be carried out.

I have never seen this done, but I believe that with javascript and HTML5 canvas, it should be completely possible.

**Question:**

How can I do this in a way that will allow me to detect a user's imperfect gesture shape input and have my scripts differentiate between the different gestures/shapes?

**Example**

[image]

**Note:**

This is not only a touch-screen function. It must work with a normal cursor as well, with the user's mouse.

**Great Uses:**

Websites can use this to allow their users to use gesture shortcuts, with both mouse and hand, to visit specific pages, or trigger functions that the user uses often within a site. For example, a user could draw a question mark on the center of any stack overflow page to be sent straight to the new question page. Users could even be allowed to make their own gestures for viewing favorite questions, going to the home page or submitting an answer for the current question page.

Comment: The shape drawing with canvas should be simple enough, but the real tricky part here that I haven't seen offered anywhere is the use of that shape for referencing against similarity to a list of shapes and connected functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been meaning to implement something like this myself but for a different use case. I wanted my users to be able to draw "circles" and "rectangles" and "diamonds" by hand and my software will substitute them with perfect circles, rectangles and diamonds instead of the original wriggly line. It's for a simple graph/chart drawing webapp I've had in mind.

Anyway, what's needed is to detect shapes from user's imperfect hand drawing. And I think I have a rough idea how to do it.

A few years ago I came across a simple toy handwriting recognition app on the Tcl wiki. It didn't use fancy AI or anything to detect letters but instead used a clever picture "hashing" technique.

The idea is basically this:

1. Divide your writing area into regions - the simplest is a grid but it can be odd shaped regions for improved accuracy.
2. When the user draws something, walk through the list of regions and detect if there's any "ink" in it.
3. If there's "ink", set the value of the region to 1. If not set it to 0. This will give you an array (or string) of 1's and 0's. If you've accumulated an array convert it to a string. This string is your drawing "hash".
4. Compare this "hash" with a database of shape hashes. An exact match is highly unlikely so use a fuzzy matching function like Levenshtein distance to find the closest match.
5. If a match is found (within reasonable threshold) then you've found your shape (in the original algorithm it was a letter or number but the idea can be generalized to shapes).

The following is one example of detecting a triangle:

```
Sample triangle:
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
0     1     2  #  3     4     .
.     .     . # # .     .     .
. . . . . . .#. .#. . . . . . .
5     .     #     #     .     .
.     .    #.     .#    .     .
. . . . . # . . . . # . . . . .
10    .  #  .     .  #  .     .
.     . #   .     .   # .     .
. . . .#. . . . . . . .#. . . .
15    #     .     .     #     .
.    #.     .     .     .#    .
. . # . . . . . . . . . . # . .
20 #  .     .     .     24 #  .
. ########################### .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

From the above ASCII art. The sample triangle in the database generates the "hash":

```
00100
01110
01010
11011
11111
```

Rearranged as a string it's: `0010001110010101101111111`.

Now let's compare a very bad user drawing of a triangle:

```
User drawing:
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
0     1     2 #   3     4     .
.     .     . # # .     .     .
. . . . . . .#. .#. . . . . . .
5     .      #     #    .     .
.     .     #     . #   .     .
. . . . . # . . . . # . . . . .
10    . #   .     . #   .     .
.     .#    .     .  #  .     .
. . . .#. . . . . . . .#. . . .
15    #     .     .      #    .
.   # .     .     .     . #   .
. .#  . . . . . . ### . .  #. .
20### .     .#### .  ## 24  # .
.    #######.     .    ###### .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Which has the hash value of: `0010001110010101111111111`. Comparing it with the original triangle in the database:

```
  triangle: 0010001110010101101111111
   drawing: 0010001110010101111111111
difference: -----------------1-------
```

Now compare the drawing to hashes of other shapes:

```
    circle: 0111011011100011101101110
   drawing: 0010001110010101111111111
difference: -1-1-1-1-111-11--1--1---1

    square: 1111110001100011000111111
   drawing: 0010001110010101111111111
difference: 11-111111111-11-111------

   diamond: 0111001010100010101001110
   drawing: 0010001110010101111111111
difference: -1-1---1--11-111-1-11---1
```

Since the triangle is the best match we assume the user is trying to draw a triangle.

There are some strategies that I've been considering to improve the reliability of the algorithm.

1. Instead of just storing 1 and 0 store 0,1,2. This makes the hash in the database a "grayscale" hash which may allow us to catch really badly drawn shapes.
2. Instead of just storing 1 and 0 store 0,1 and "don't care" which may allows us to filter out noise in the drawing and may improve matching.
3. Instead of using a fixed grid get the bounding rect of the drawing then divide the drawing up into the regions. This allows us to detect circles and ovals with the same hash and squares and rectangles with the same hash. It also caters for drawings that are smaller or larger than expected.

As to how to record the drawing - that's up to you. You can use a canvas, SVG or even just polling mouse coordinates using onmousemove.

Comment: This is impressive, a perfect answer kind sir. Thanks!